# Simultaneous Perl SSH Sessions

Tags: perl, ssh

I am wondering if anyone has a Perl script (or can write one) to execute on multiple hosts at once via *ssh*, without any modules. I used to have something like this but cannot find it now and can't remember how it was done.

Comment: Accept the answers you receive for the the questions you post if you find them right.Seems like you have not accepted any answer till now.

Comment: It’s unclear what you mean by “without any modules”, but I doubt you’ll get working code that uses *no modules whatsoever.* At the very least, you’d to load the `Socket` module; probably if you went that route you’d grab `IO::Socket` and `IO::Select`. All those are core modules that Perl ships with. If what you mean by “without any modules” is that it must run “without resorting to any additional CPAN modules”, then while perhaps possible, it would certainly be pointlessly difficult compared with pulling in those 3rd-party CPAN modules that are specifically dedicated to doing precisely this.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for [ClusterSSH](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=Main_Page)? It's Perl, and it's used to run the same commands on several hosts at once, so this might be what you're looking for...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using [Expect.pm](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Expect/Expect.pod) which is similar to [@cnicutar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714501/cnicutar)'s suggestion of calling an Expect script from Perl, except that you write it all in Perl. *(This of course down not fit the requirement of "without any modules", but that requirement leads to bad Perl )*

Answer (score 2):

1. Learn how to install and use modules even when you don't have admin privileges on the host
2. Use [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH%3a%3aParallel)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use any additional modules from CPAN or any other source , all I can recommend you are:

1) Use Expect script and call it internally in your Perl script [Only if you are not willing to use Expect.pm module]

2) Use SSH keygen in all the servers to which you will connect to , so that password wont be necessary in the script. As mentioned by "cnicutar"

3) Use "remsh" if SSH usage is not that necessary.